# How to make table row height dynamically editable

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Is there any possibility to change `html table row` size dynamically (Resize rows height drag & drop) like this (https://reactdatagrid.io/docs/row-resize) but free.

Answer (score 1):

if you want instead a HTML, CSS, vanilla javascript (no library) example, here is it:

> like you see in the GIF, the size is automatically changable

[image]

> I am using the `contentEditable` API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

```js
let th = document.querySelectorAll("th");
let td = document.querySelectorAll("td");

[th, td].forEach((elAll) => {
  elAll.forEach((el) => {
    el.contentEditable = "true";
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <!-- here they will have a contentEditable attribute
         <th contenteditable>your content</th>
      -->
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>StackOverFlow</td>
    <td>myName</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Facebook</td>
    <td>my second Name</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>my third Name</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Microsoft</td>
    <td>my fourth Name</td>
    <td>America</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> the result will be something like this:
> [image]

---

BUT if this seems to hard for you,

a simple excel solution can be using an online open source library that technically is easier and will add more functionalities.

you can do some research on google and you will find it:

- for example, in react I found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spreadsheet

[image]

> all the technical stuff is done by another dev, you just need to import the library, read docs, and build

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, but i am looking for possibility just change height of table row.

Comment: There a lot of library that change width of column, but no one which can change height of row.

Comment: @AliaksandrVysotskiy if you use ENTER key it will change the height also, see image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk7lR.png